# UNEXPECTED MATH error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am using appgyver and when trying to connect steroids i get an "UNEXPECTED MATH" error
what does that mean? and how to fix it?

```
    steroids.config.location = http://localhost/index.html
steroids.config.tabBar.enabled = true
steroids.config.tabBar.tabs = [
  {
      title: "Index"
      icon: "icons/pill@2x.png"
      location: "http://localhost/index.html"
  },
 {
      title: "DeviceInfos"
      icon: "icons/pill@2x.png"
      location: "http://localhost/DeviceInfo.html"
  },
  {
  title: "Test"
  icon: "icons/pill@2x.png"
  location : "http://localhost/tutorial.html"
  }
]
steroids.config.tabBar.tintColor = "#123456"
steroids.config.tabBar.tabTitleColor = "#654321"
steroids.config.tabBar.tabTitleShadowColor = "#333333"
steroids.config.tabBar.selectedTabTintColor = "#099900"
steroids.config.tabBar.backgroundImage = "images/tabs_background@2x.png"

steroids.config.drawers =
  left:
    id: "leftDrawer"
    location: "http://localhost/left.html"
    showOnAppLoad: true
    widthOfDrawerInPixels: 200
  right:
    id: "rightDrawer"
    location: "http://localhost/right.html"
    showOnAppLoad: false
    widthOfDrawerInPixels: 200
  options:
    centerViewInteractionMode: "Full"
    closeGestures: ["PanNavBar", "PanCenterView", "TapCenterView"]
    openGestures: ["PanNavBar", "PanCenterView"]
    showShadow: true
    stretchDrawer: true
    widthOfLayerInPixels: 0

steroids.config.navigationBar.tintColor = "#888888"
steroids.config.navigationBar.titleColor = "#345612"
steroids.config.navigationBar.titleShadowColor = "#998822"

steroids.config.navigationBar.buttonTintColor = "#998822"
steroids.config.navigationBar.buttonTitleColor = "#345612"
steroids.config.navigationBar.buttonShadowColor = "#888888"
```

the problem is in this page i think because even when deleting the html pages the error stays

Comment: Have you tried going through your code commenting out bits of it and from there you can find the exact line?

Comment: yeah i tried that and i couldn't  find where the error comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
steroids.config.location = http://localhost/index.html
```

which should be

```
steroids.config.location = "http://localhost/index.html"
```

Without the quotation marks the value is interpreted as some sort of mathematical equation (because of the slashes in the path), which will understandably result in errors.